# Mark Line with Error in code sample

Tags: discussion, questions, code-formatting

I read quite a few question on stackoverflow now, and I came across one thing that I think is very inconvenient: If somebody posts an error log which only tells you the line of the error, you either have to count or copy the code (both only works for the full code) to find the line with the error.

Isn't it possible to add an option in the code part where you can *mark* the error line? So it would be displayed as a red line for example. I think this would be so extremely useful in many scenarios.

There should be a clearly visible option for this, so that even beginners know how to use this feature.

Comment: Or line numbers in code blocks, those would be nice.

Comment: but this would still only help for complete codes (from beginning to end). but still it is a good idea